# Custom Overlay MKMapOverlay iOS port of Android method

Tags: android, iphone, mkoverlay

I have an android app I have written, that basically has a custom overlay, in this overlay I have overwritten the DRAW method to draw something on a canvas and at the end of my DRAW override, I call the super DRAW passing in the canvas I have painted.. the result is, every time the map is modified in anyway my custom overlay is redrawn as expected.

Now, I am trying to accomplish the same thing on iPhone and am getting a little confused.

Basically I need something drawn in the top right corner of the map every time a redraw occurs of the map. The drawin will change change with every update as well so can't simply be put a view over the map and pass touches through etc.

So, I guess the question is, what is the euivalent of the DRAW method in iOS.. how would I roughly accomplish this same thing?  There are MKOverlayView in the API, but there seem to be some significant differences.. So, how do I put something say at 10x10 over the map, whos size is variable and make sure every time the map is moved, scaled or otherwised interacted with this object is redrawn at location 10x10 on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for MKMapView state that you should not subclass MKMapView, so you can't / shouldn't override the drawRect method. You could add a UIView, though, and override drawRect to do your custom drawing.